# Gitlab runner: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I setup my own GitLab server a few days a go and everything is working as it should. Now I found out about GitLab runner and I wanna try deploying my application over that. Before describing my problem I will quickly go over how my network works.

I have a nginx proxy manager which redirects incoming traffic to the correct docker container it then also applies a wild card certificate. I should also comment that the GitLab server and GitLab runner are not the same container but are in the same network.

My first problem is that as soon I create a runner inside GitLab (Admin Area  -> CI/CD  -> Runner) seems to be created but I'm prompt with an popup that [the connection for this site is not secure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMm29.png). The odd part is that GitLab tries redirecting me to my domain and a port with **shouldn't happen**. However I found out that I can just remove the port which does the trick. I then get the Register runner site with the runner token and a step by step guide.

Then I thought lets try adding the runner to the GitLab Runner Container, but that resulted in a second error which makes me believe that there is generally something wrong with my setup since I get an [http: server gave HTTP response to a HTTPS client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OW9G.png)

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
  gitlab:
    container_name: gitlab
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2224
        nginx['listen_port'] = 8929
        nginx['listen_https'] = false
        postgresql['enable'] = false
        gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = 'postgresql'
        gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = 'utf8'
        gitlab_rails['db_host'] = 'postgres'
        gitlab_rails['db_port'] = '5432'
        gitlab_rails['db_username'] = 'gitlab'
        gitlab_rails['db_password'] = 'mysecurepassword'
    ports:
      - 8929:8929
      - 2224:22
    volumes:
      - ./config:/etc/gitlab
      - ./logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - ./data:/var/opt/gitlab
    shm_size: 256m
networks:
  default:
    name: homelab-network
    external: true
```

I'm kind of lost on this problem and don't real have a clue on what to try.